# Verifying if a general linear set is a group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

This is an example from my text:

Let $\textit{F}$ be any of $Q,R,C,Z$ or$ Z_{p}\left (p is a prime.
 \right)$

The set $GL\left(2,\textit{F} \right)$ of all 2 x 2 matrices with nonzero determinants and entries from F is a non-Abelian group under matrix multiplication.

As in example 17, when F is $Z_{p}$, modulo p arithmetic is used to calculate determinants, the matrix products and inverses.

The formula given in Example 9 for the inverse of 
$\begin{bmatrix}
a &b \\ 
 c&d 
\end{bmatrix}$

remains valid for elements from $GL\left(2,Z_{p} \right)$provided we interpret division by ad-bc as multiplication by the inverse of ad-bc modulo p.

For example, in $GL\left(2,Z_{7} \right), consider 
\begin{bmatrix}
4 &5 \\ 
6 &3 
\end{bmatrix}$.

Then the determinant $\left(ad-bc \right)mod7 is \left(12-30 \right)$ mod 7 =-18mod7=3mod7 and the inverse of 3 is 
5 $\left[\left(3.5 \right)mod 7=1 \right]$
So the inverse of 
$\begin{bmatrix}
 4&5 \\ 
 6&3 
\end{bmatrix} 
is 
\begin{bmatrix}
 3.5&2.5 \\ 
 1.5&4.5 
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
 1& 3\\ 
 5& 6
\end{bmatrix}$

There are a couple of confusions that I am facing that it is hard to know where to begin with. In my opinion the author did a rather lazy and hazy way to put his explanation across.

1) The operation in question is the modulo p. So why is there any talk about matrix product?

2) The author mentioned that the inverse of the matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}
4 &5 \\ 
 6& 3
\end{bmatrix}
$
is 
$
\begin{bmatrix}
3.5 &2.5 \\ 
1.5 & 4.5
\end{bmatrix}$
Where did the latter matrix comes from? I can see that he attempted to provide an explanation but it is really obscure after having trying for a long time to make sense of what he is saying.

3) 
The requirement for what it requires for a set to be a group is clear to me.
In the case, however, for a GL set, there seems to be some slight differences in the techniques used to verify whether a general linear set is a group.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: The claim is not true for $F = \mathbb{Z}$ where you need determinant to be $\pm 1$ for it to be invertible.

Answer (score 1):

1. The operation is matrix multiplication modulo $p$. [Just multiply the matrices normally, and then consider each entry modulo $p$.]
2. For real $2 \times 2$ matrices, the formula for the inverse is $\frac{1}{ad-bc} \begin{bmatrix}d & -b \\ -c & a\end{bmatrix}$. The formula for the inverse in $GL(2,Z_p)$ is the same, except now $\frac{1}{ad-bc}$ is taken to be the multiplicative inverse of $ad-bc$ modulo $p$. In the example, $ad-bc=-18$, which is equivalent to $3$ modulo $7$. The inverse of $3$ modulo $7$ is $5$ (since $3 \cdot 5 = 15 \equiv 1 \mod 7$). Plugging this into $\frac{1}{ad-bc} \begin{bmatrix}d & -b \\ -c & a\end{bmatrix}$ gives the matrix above.
3. I don't really see what you mean when you say that verifying that this is a group requires different techniques. Just verify the group axioms.

Comment: Why is the inverse of 3 mod 7 = 5?
Is there a theorem where this result follows?

Comment: @Mathematicing Every nonzero element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (when $p$ is prime) has a multiplicative inverse, so you can just try all those elements ($1,2,\ldots,6$) until you find some $k$ such that $3k\equiv 1 \mod 7$.

Comment: Can closure and associativity be tested?

Comment: @Mathematicing Associativity follows from associativity of matrix multiplication and the modulo operation (can be verified directly). For closure, it suffices to show that the product of two matrices in the group is still in the group, that is, that the product is still invertible.